# Is it possible to authenticate on Instagram API by curl or in the application backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, instagram, instagram-api

After Instagram updated their API on June 1, I couldn't get the [access token](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) without logging in to Instagram account.

Is it possible to skip the website authentication and do it by curl or in my application backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by using [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) gem for Ruby

I made self method in `InstagramPage` class:

```
def self.instagram_client
  return @instagram_client if @instagram_client.present? &&
         @instagram_client.access_token.present?

  # Logging in to Instagram
  url = Instagram.authorize_url(redirect_uri: ENV['INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL'], 
                                response_type: 'token')
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.get(url)
  agent.page.forms[0]['username'] = ENV['INSTAGRAM_USERNAME']
  agent.page.forms[0]['password'] = ENV['INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD']
  agent.page.forms[0].submit

  # Retrieving access_token from url and setting it to Instagram client
  access_token = agent.page.uri.to_s.split('=')[-1]
  @instagram_client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
end
```

Now I able to call client by running `InstagramPage.instagram_client`

Comment: What is the url you are using? I am trying to use mechanize to also log into my instagram account, but it is not picking up on the login form. `agent.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')` but `agent.page.forms` is nil. Not sure what the deal is. It's not recognizing any forms on that page.

Comment: others have said you cannot use mechanize to log into instagram because of no react support. I ended up using watir to log in and retrieve necessary data. works great.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but just in case anyone finds this you need to use the old login URL.  `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login`

This will allow you to use Mechanize to login, save any relevant cookies.